# Error during CMake libnfc

Tags: installation, cmake, nfc, lib-nfc

I'm really trying hard to install libnfc but i keep ketting the error:

[image]

It says:

- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
- CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindPCRE.cmake:30 (MESSAGE):
- Could not find PCRE
- Call Stack (most recent call first):
- CMakeLists.txt:112 (FIND_PACKAGE)

Is there anyone who knows how i can fix this error? You will help me very much. If you have another example of a NFC libary thats oké to!

Comment: `Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)` Most likely you did not install Doxygen. You will not be able to generate documentation without that. http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/download.html#srcbin

Answer (score 0):

I already have the answer. When i added the **LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS** and the **LIBUSB_LIBARIES** entry CMake added a lot of configuration. With the configuration of below it worked.
[image]

Comment: Since there is no standard place to put libraries and includes on windows cmake a lot of times will have to be told where to find these. For my applications I make a lot of use of environment variables and using these to set LIBNAME_DIR variables.